# Only one option is correct

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

$a \in \mathbb{C}$

Which is the correct option:
1) $a = 1$
2) $a = 42$
3) $a = i =\sqrt{-1}$
4) $0^a \in \mathbb{C}$
5) $a^3 = 1$

Hint 1:

> Read the title.

Hint 2:

> If only **one** option is right, the other options must be wrong.

Comment: You should really write $i$ instead of $\sqrt {-1}$ which is a very misleading notation (there is just one step from there to thinking that $i$ is **the** complex number whose square is $-1$).

Comment: Thank You for the feedback, but I do not understand. I wrote $\sqrt{-1}$ as I felt that it would be more clear because not everyone uses $i$ as the complex part of a number. Also, I am confused, because $i$ is defined as the number that on squaring equals to $-1$.

Comment: @KartikSoneji; -i squares to -1 too, i is defined as the positive square root of -1.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry That is very much not true! $i$ is not positive! $i$ is defined as *a* number *whose square* is $-1$. To use $\sqrt{\cdot}$ with complex numbers, you need to figure out how to define it, which isn't as easy as you'd think. (You have to choose a branch cut: say, $\sqrt{\cdot}$ gives the number whose argument is in $[0,\pi)$.) And it doesn't interact as nicely with exponents anymore.

Comment: @Deusovi; any number $e^{i\pi\pm k\frac{i\pi}{2}}$ squares to $-1$, of which $i$ is the primitive value $e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$ - which is - excuse the pun - a bit of a circular definition!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry But $i$ is not defined in terms of itself; it is simply defined as a number that squares to $-1$. Just because you *can* express that in terms of itself doesn't mean that's how the definition works.

Comment: @Deusovi; I was taught it like this: Let $\pmatrix{a\\b}\times\pmatrix{c\\d}=\pmatrix{ac-bd\\ad+bc}$. Then $\pmatrix{0\\1}\times\pmatrix{0\\1}=\pmatrix{-1\\0}$

Comment: @JonMarkPerry There is no intrinsic way to make a difference between the two roots of the polynomial $X^2+1$. That is the core idea behind Galois theory. In other words, $i$ is a symbol to denote one of them, and it should always be referred to as **a** root of $-1$ (as in all of Deusovi's comments).

Answer (score 3):

I suppose any of

> 3, 4, or 5 could be correct.

because

> both $i$ and $-i$ work for 3

and

> any real number that isn't 1 or 42 works for 4

and

> $\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ or $-\frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ works for 5

Note:

> According to Wolfram, $0^i$ is undefined

Comment: Your last comment is the reason why the problem is ill-posed.

Comment: Added the Solution.

Comment: There is one correct answer that makes all the other options wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=1$ then

> it is also true that $0^a\in \mathbb{C}$ and that $a^3=1$, so option 1 cannot be the only correct one.

In fact,

> $0^a\in \mathbb{C}$ is straightforwardly true for any nonzero $a$, which means that none of options 1,2,3,5 can possibly be the only correct one.

Therefore, if "only one option is correct" then

> it must be option 4, which will e.g. be the only correct option if $a=2$.

Comment: Added the Solution.

Comment: But if Option 4 is correct, then Option 1, Option 2 and Option 5 **may** also be correct. Note that they may be correct, and do not have to be correct, but there **is** only one option correct, Thus, Option 4 must be wrong.

Comment: Bleh. I don't like this question, but I do have to retract my statement that $0^a=0$ is straightforwardly true for any nonzero $a$. I had it in my head that as $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$, all the (in general infinitely many) possible values of $\varepsilon^a$ have modulus $\rightarrow0$, but actually that's entirely untrue and I agree with Kartik that the best convention is to leave $0^{\textrm{anything}}$ undefined, at least if the "anything" isn't real.

Answer (score -6):

Solution:

> **Assuming: Option 1 is correct**.
> That means Option 4, and Option 5 **must** also be correct.
> But only one option can be correct, so Option 1 cannot be correct.
>
> **Assuming: Option 2 is correct**.
> That means Option 4 **must** also be correct.
> But only one option can be correct, so Option 2 cannot be correct.
>
> **Assuming: Option 4 is correct**.
> That means Option 1, Option 2, and Option 3 **may** be correct.
> But only one option may be correct, so Option 4 cannot be correct.
>
> **Assuming: Option 5 is correct**.
> That means Option 1 **must** also be correct.
> But only one option can be correct, so Option 5 cannot be correct.
>
> **Assuming: Option 3 is correct**.
> Then:
> Option 1 **must** be wrong(contradiction).
> Option 2 **must** be wrong(contradiction).
> Option 4 **must** be wrong, because
> $0^i$ is undefined, and $\notin \mathbb{C}$.
> Option 5 **must** be wrong, because $i^3 = -i$.
> So, **Option 3 is the right answer**.

Comment: If option 3 is correct, then option 4 is correct; your manipulations there are invalid for multiple reasons. For starters, $a^{(b^c)}$ is not the same as $(a^b)^c$.

Comment: @Deusovi Fair point. I have edited the answer.

Comment: $(0^b)^c = 0^{bc}$ is only true when you already know both sides are defined. Otherwise you could say $0^3 = (0^{-1})^-3$, which is undefined.

Comment: You've left the same error intact. Manipulating $0^i$ isn't necessary at all; you can make the point you're trying to make there by simply asserting: $0^i$ is undefined, and $\notin \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I think the major confusion here is that what you MEAN is: "The correct answer is the one that is mutually exclusive of all the others."  but what you SAID is: "If only one option is right, the other options must be wrong." ... those don't exactly mean the same thing.  If you're relying on exact interpretation, you need to give exact formulation.

Comment: @Rubio I do not understand. If only one option is correct, the other options **have** to be wrong.

Comment: But it's possible for 4 to be correct and the others wrong. It's true that "if exactly one option is correct, and option X is correct, then all other options are wrong". It's not true that "if exactly one option is correct, and *without that restriction* it's possible for X and Y to both be correct (or X individually), then both X and Y are wrong".

Comment: Say I have a deck of cards, and I tear up the 8 of hearts. I deal three cards face down and tell you "All three cards have the same number, and the middle card is red." You can't say "the middle card isn't the 6 of hearts, because it's possible for the middle card to be a 6 of hearts and the left card to be a 6 of diamonds -- those are both red!" This logic doesn't work -- you can't conclude that the middle card is the 8 of diamonds. It *could* be the 8 of diamonds. But it could also be the 6 of diamonds, or the king of hearts.

Comment: @Deusovi There is not only the $0^a$ issue, in the OP's solution it is claimed that $a^3=1$ implies $a=1$. There should be an option to vote for closing questions for being nonsensical.

Comment: @Deusovi Just to be clear, I mean that if $a^3 = 1$ then $a = 1$ is a **possibility**, not a certainty.

Comment: @KartikSoneji Yes, it is, but *only from the perspective of not having that first restriction*. If you have that restriction that you have imposed, then "4 only" is a perfectly valid solution. You use the "only one is correct" restriction for your own solution, but you disregard it for the "condition 4 only" solution. Again, take my deck of cards example.

Comment: Suppose $a=2$. Then only Option $4$ is correct.